# Weird case-insensitive behaviour in WPF - can you please explain

Tags: wpf

Can someone please explain this to me:

I have removed the startupUri in my application and moved it to the app class.

```
<Application x:Class="My.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            ><!-- StartupUri="/Forms/MainWindow.xaml"-->
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I accidently typed "mainWindow" with a lower case in "var mainWindow" but I reference it with an upper case in "MainWindow.Show();".

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
         var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
         MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Please note that `MainWindow` doesn't refer to the class here, but in fact to the lowercase `mainWindow` object.

Why is this then working fine? I thought it should throw an compiler error?
How can `mainWindow` and `MainWindow` refer to the same object?

Comment: sorry @thumbmunkeys ... and I removed that comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application has a main window of type MainWindow which initially is "MainWindow" generated in your project. If you use a instance, or this property the result should be the same.

Here you have a picture with the application content and the MainWindow property:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The MainWindow object you're accessing with MainWindow.Show() is actually a property of the Application class. It's just a coincidence that your main window is also called 'MainWindow'.

According to MSDN, the Application.MainWindow property "is automatically set with a reference to the first Window object to be instantiated in the AppDomain."

Your code `var mainWindow = new MainWindow();` is effectively doing that: instantiating the first instance of a Window object in your AppDomain. So the subsequent attempt to access Application.MainWindow will return your newly created Window object.

The behaviour is correct, but it *is* a little confusing.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and hence @thumbmunkeys was guiding OP in right direction